# WSO2 Identity Server - Entitlement for PEP - Error: Invalid Remote Address at Web Service Login

Tags: wso2, identity, entitlements

When testing a programmatic entitlement (login) to the WSO2 Version 5 server using the samples  published in blogs, I get the following error message:

```
.Jul 15, 2015 2:50:41 PM org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.StAXDialectDetector detectDialect
WARNING: Unable to determine dialect of the StAX implementation at jar:file:/home/claudef/tmp/wso2/entitlement/lib/axiom_1.2.11.wso2v4.jar!/
 org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Authentication Failed : Invalid remote address passed - https://ralbz001098.cloud.dst.ibm.com:9443/
```

My code is as followed:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",
                           "/home/claudef/tmp/wso2/entitlement/resources/wso2carbon.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "xxxxxxxxx");

//initialize authentication admin stub
UnitTest1 remoteEntitlementClient = new UnitTest1();
//login using authentication admin stub providing valid credentials
// add IP address as a third argument is not working!
//  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30452073/wso2-identity-server-authenticationadmin-api-authentication-failed
// remoteEntitlementClient.login("admin", "xxxxxxxx","localhost");
remoteEntitlementClient.login("admin", "xxxxxxxx");
//initialize entitlement service stub with obtained authentication cookie
remoteEntitlementClient.initUnitTest1();
```

### Libraries linked:

```
. org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub-4.2.0.jar
. org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.common-4.2.1.jar
. org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.stub-4.2.1.jar
. org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.ui-4.0.0.jar 
. axiom_1.2.11.wso2v4.jar
```

Thanks in advance for support.

Comment: Found the solution. The third argument is required and must be in the format of a valid IP address like "localhost", or IP address like 9.X.X.X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. The third argument is required inside the login and must be in the format of a local IP address like "localhost", or a valid IP address like 9.X.X.X. The right place to add it is in the login section, for example:

```
boolean loggedIn = authstub.login(username, password, "9.x.x.xx");
```

The login code is working now.

Comment: It works for me. use authstub.login(username, password, "127.0.0.1"); if you are running it localy.